# displaying JPEG images

Tags: display, data, vga, imageprocessing

I want to display images(JPEG) stored in a SD card, I want the output to be VGA so that I can display them in readily available display modules.

Any idea on how this can be done?

Comment: This is soo soo soo very broad. I mean, like "use a computer" or "a smartphone can do that" broad.

Answer (score 2):

Any board with an SD card slot and VGA out (even without!) should do it, e.g.

- Arduino with SD shield and [VGA shield](http://www.strichlabs.com/pages/vga-shield), or [not](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11608) (memory gonna be tiiiight)
- Beaglebone with [VGA cape](http://circuitco.com/support/index.php?title=BeagleBone_VGA)
- [Windows 8 Surface Pro](http://www.microsoft.com/Surface/en-AU/surface-with-windows-8-pro) with display port to VGA adaptor
- [Amiga 500 HxC](http://torlus.com/floppy/forum/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1147)

Perhaps we can whittle down the choices if you provide some more info about your project, as at the moment it is a broad shopping question that will get closed or just opinionated answers. :)

Have a look at this project, is this what you are after?

http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2012/06/04/nokia-qvga-tft-lcd-for-the-arduino-mega-graphics-library-part-2-of-2/